# Default in a Javascript Switch Statement works with just one case, but not two?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

When I wrote this code with just one `case`, the alert fired just fine when I clicked a `case` other than 1 or 2.  When I added more than one, the default no longer fires the alert when I click a `case` other then 1 or 2.  What gives?  Thank you in advance.

```
function displayLoc(locNum) {

    switch (locNum) {

        case 1:
            $('#loc-name').html('Google');
            $('#loc-web').attr('href','http://www.google.com');
          break;

        case 2:
            $('#loc-name').html('StackOverflow');
            $('#loc-web').attr('href','http://www.stackoverflow.com');
          break;

        default:
            alert('Location coming soon!');
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it by any chance that locNum is 2?

Comment: JavaScript does in fact work, so I suspect something else is going on.

Comment: Add  a `console.log()` call to see what "locNum" is, and to verify that you're actually making it into the function.

Comment: Ok it must be something else, I'll keep searching.  Thanks for the support!!

Comment: Thank you.  I'll try logging it into the console.

Comment: Need jsfiddle.for more clarity

Comment: looks fine at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tabzE/2/

Comment: So surprisingly, the alert doesn't fire when I view the site locally running XAMPP, but when I uploaded the files, the alert works fine!  Strange!

http://sectorfive.com/wallbeds/locator.php  (Click on the numbers on the Florida map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems just fine. It must be something else.

However may I suggest you a different solution?

```
var locations = [
    ['Google', 'http://www.google.com'],
    ['StackOverflow', 'http://www.stackoverflow.com']
];

function displayLoc(locNum) {
    var loc = locations[locNum];

    if (!loc) {
        alert('Location coming soon!');
        return;
    }

    $('#loc-name').html(loc[0]);
    $('#loc-web').attr('href', loc[1]);
}
```

Comment: Ah use an object!  That would save a lot of code and time.  Which seems to be what programming is all about :)  Thank you.